# Sign Up for a Trailhead Playground with Einstein Lead Scoring

Tags: leads, trailhead, einstein, developer-org

By following the below steps from Salesforce Trailhead "***Sign Up for a Trailhead Playground with Einstein Lead Scoring***", I am able to create a new org with Einstein Lead Scoring.

[image: Salesforce Trailhead Image]

But while verifying the step for "Hands-on Challenge" I am getting this error "***Sign up for a Trailhead Playground with Einstein Lead Scoring using the link in the instructions.***"

[image: Trailhead Challenge error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its **resolved** with the same Org.
In my experience, the "**Launch**" button and the "**Verify step**" button doesn't get the right org.
Please refresh the challenge page or try it by log out and log in trailhead again and make sure that the selected playground was the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that new dev org is linked to your trailhead account, also, make sure the org used to verify the challenge is a dev rather than a playground - if all this fails, then refreshing would be your best bet

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE Chris. I highly recommend you visit the [Help] and take the Tour to better understand how this Forum works. You've provided a new answer to a question that already has an accepted answer. As such it doesn't add help the person who posted the question since it has already been solved although it might be of benefit to someone else who searches on the subject.